# Получение сожержимого Web страницы с задержкой (после полной загрузки)

Tags: c#, httpclient, httpwebrequest

Есть страничка в интернете. Вот [ссылка](https://dom.gosuslugi.ru/#!/organizationView/c5a5aeb3-4c28-4558-b472-abfa87f98ec3) на страницу. В ней содержится табличка с данными. Пытаюсь ее скачать.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(tbBaseURI.Text);
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();           
Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
string s = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
```

Страница скачивается, но вместо таблицы вижу надпись загрузка данных. По сути, нужно ~5 сек, что бы таблица загрузилась.

Как же получить полностью загруженную страницу? Может можно как-то сделать запрос, а начинать читать через 5 сек.

Comment: Не выйдет, там же загрузка контента через ajax, а это javascript. Смотрите в сторону каких нибудь браузерных движков, которые умеют JS.

Comment: Или смотрите откуда страничка качает данные для таблицы и вместо того, чтобы дергать страничку, качайте данные напрямую.

Comment: Как же я устал людей отговаривать от неправильных действий в виде селениума и других ненужных агрегаторов. Это же в 90% лишнее, совсем! Будто вы хотите прихлопнуть комара, но у вас не получается и вы запускаете ядерную ракету по городу. Почти любой подобный сайт отдает данные при помощи API и этот [не исключение](https://dom.gosuslugi.ru/ppa/api/rest/services/ppa/public/organizations/orgByGuid?organizationGuid=c5a5aeb3-4c28-4558-b472-abfa87f98ec3).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ подскажите тогда, как получить данные из следующего запроса по (он идет через один после указанного вами)   /ppa/api/rest/services/ppa/public/organizations/additionalinfo . Это раздел дополнительной информации. Сервер просто так ее не отдает.

Comment: @MaximK Ну смотрите, это POST запрос. Открываете как показано в ссылке, что я вам давал программу Postman, заносите туда адрес, выбираете POST тип запроса, отправляете. В ответ вам сервер дает `Cannot consume content type`, думаем логически, `Content type` - это один из заголовков, пробуем поставить его таким, как на оригинальном запросе, отправляем и видим, что сервер теперь нам дает `No content to map to Object due to end of input`, то есть у нас нет контента. Тип контента мы задали в заголовке как `application/json`, значит и контент надо отправлять в виде JSON.

Comment: Идем в `Body`, ставим тип `Raw` (JSON) и копируем туда контент из запроса (`{"organizationGuids":["c5a5aeb3-4c28-4558-b472-abfa87f98ec3"]}`), пробуем отправить и видим, что сервер нам успешно отдал все нужные данные. Исходя из этого, вам при отправке запроса нужно установить заголовок `Content-Type` и отправить данные в формате JSON. Кстати, вы используете давно устаревший класс `HttpWebRequest`, советую перейти на новый, созданный для этого класс `HttpClient` (об этом можете почитать в документации), а с ним вам и заголовки трогать даже не придется, лишь грамотное создание `StringContent`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо! Очень ценный для меня совет!